# How to logout another user in 10.8?

Tags: macos, login

With 10.6 I used to kill the process `loginwindow` to logout another user, but with 10.8 I noticed that even if I do so, many processes from that user stay active.

So, is there a way to logout another user in 10.8, other than logging him in or manually killing all his processes?

Comment: OS X now runs process as users even when they haven't logged in for the first time. What problem exactly are you seeking to solve? You can still kill all processes for a specific user and then know the remaining processes were started by the system.

Comment: @bmike not exactly: if an user never logged in since power up, I see no process belonging to him. The problem I'm trying to solve is, as I said, to logout an user without having to switch to his account to do that.

Comment: Hmm - all my systems start launchd, distnoted and cfprefsd processes for each local user when the machine starts whether anyone is logged in or not.

Comment: @bmike I believe you, not sure why it doesn't happen here

Comment: Just wait till you get to Mavericks when user processes stick around running even after you log that user out from the GUI. I don't doubt what you're seeing either :-)

Comment: @bmike I've made some more tries, and even here in 10.8 some processes stick around after you logout actually, though they don't start until they login (as I was saying earlier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an administrator:

```
sudo su - user_to_be_logged_out
kill -9 -1
```

That will log out any user by ending all of the user processes. Use care to not issue the kill -9 -1 as root else some work would be expected to be lost as the system would immediately self-destroy all processes.

There are of course one line commands, but I like having a pause to look and make sure I switched to the correct user before issuing a powerful command like `kill -9 -1` and I also avoid at all costs having sudo appear before that kill since I don't even want to kill all processes as root.

Answer (score 2):

Like bmike mentioned but combining the commands into an alias that can be used in /bin/tcsh shell. Again this is nice and fast but be careful. Don’t do this on root or yourself.

```
alias ku "sudo su user_to_be_logged_out -c 'kill -9 -1'"
```